# passing parameter from multiple jquery mobile page

Tags: jquery, json, rest, mobile

here is what i have been battling with for a couple of weeks now and i am hoping someone can help. i have two tables that i am returning json data from, table 1 return a list of category of product, table 2 returns product list. i have manage to wire up the json data return from the category table to a listview in my query mobile app my challenge now is i can't seem to get my listview to display products information when i click a category - i am using multipage app with jquery mobile pls help

sumary  - 
i need to know how to pass an id of selected product category to append to the REST call i am making to get the products details.

Please if you need more clarity i will post it here.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create page

**product.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="product_page">
        <div data-role="header" class="">
             <h3>Home</h3>            
        </div>
        <div role="main" id="" class="ui-content">   
            <ul data-role="listview" id="product_list"></ul>  
        </div>
    </div>         
 </body>
 <script>

 var product = {
 "product": [
 {
  "product_name": "Product 1",
  "product_category": "1"
 },
 {
  "product_name": "Product 2",
  "product_category": "2"
 },
 {
  "product_name": "Product 3",
  "product_category": "3"
 }
 ]
 }

 $("#product_page").on("pageshow", function(event){
   var list = "";
   $.each(product, function(key, value){
      $.each(value, function(key, value){
        list += '<li><a href="category.html?product_category='+value.product_category+'" data-ajax="false">'+value.product_name+'</a></li>';
    })

    })    
     $("#product_list").html(list).trigger("create")
     $("#product_list").listview( "refresh" )
 })
</script>
<html>
```

**category.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">  </script>
</head>

<body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="category_page">
       <div data-role="header" class=""></div>
       <div role="main" id="" class="ui-content">   
         <p id="detail"></p>
       </div>
    </div> 
</body>
<script>

$("#category_page").on("pageshow", function(event){
    var product_category = getParameterByName("product_category");
    $("#detail").html(product_category);    
})   
/** GET PARAMETER **/
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ved. This definitely gives me the solution I am looking. On the other note. Is it advisable to return 1 big json data that contains both the product category and products in the pageinit call and then manipulate it the way you have showed above or I should make a json call on every click on the categoryitem to filter the list of products. thank you for your help